# eclipse:default package always visible

Tags: eclipse

Today I suddenly find the default package always visible in my all project.
I don't know what happened and what can I do to hide it.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Click on the `down arrow of this package explorer window` (it displays the option for package explorer)
2. Check `1 Empty parent packages`

Comment: Actually it should be checked - the checked items are the ones not shown.

Comment: I have edited and this time, it works! Sorry for my first answer.

Comment: Thanks.But I don't know who need the option to show the empty default package?